# sending GCM push notification with image using c# .net (for android application)

Tags: c#, android, .net, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

> i am using this c# code to send push notification using GCM site 
>   but i also want to send image with notification title and message.
>   please tell me how this can be achieved.
>   i am trying to add "data.image" parameter to add image with notification but on getting notification image is not getting added.

i have also passed "data.image" with image url that can be accessed globally but nothing is happening.

```
 var applicationID = "some_id";
            // SENDER_ID is nothing but your ProjectID (from API Console- google code)//                                          
            var SENDER_ID = "My-Id";
            var value = message;
            var title = titl;
            //var image = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/887989/antshot.png";


            //var imgstat = "http://justcash.co.in/img/logo0011.png";
            WebResponse tResponse;
            WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
            tRequest.Method = "post";
            tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));

            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));
            string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=1000&delay_while_idle=1&data.title=" + title + "&data.message="
                 + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + regId + "&data.image=" + "some-image-source";

            //string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=1000&delay_while_idle=1&data.title=" + title + "&data.message="
            //    + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&data.image=" + image + "&registration_id=" + regId + "";


            Console.WriteLine(postData);
            Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();
            dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

            tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

            sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
            tReader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            tResponse.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly send an image in GCM, you need to add url of the image in data, which handled on the receiver side to show result

GCM are limited in size and works as JSON

Comment: i have passed data.image parameter with image url on it but nothing is happening when i get notification.

Comment: on client side, u need to handle the message data and load the image.

Comment: What is the client side? Android? IOS? or Web?

Comment: client side is android ... using this code i want to send push notification to android phones with image showing in notification using phonegap

Comment: Then ill suggest u to use firebase FCM as GCM is obsolete. Second in Android side when message is received get the data and load the Image in Url and then generate the notification accordingly. If u are using default u need to override and create it